# PHP - add up numbers with new insert

Tags: php, symfony, setter, symfony-3.4

I am adding new entities within my Symfony project.

On every entity set up I added a word. I need to add up a number from 1 to ... with each entity with the same name is added.

In example:

```
    username = $entity->getUsername() . '-added' +1;
    $email = $entity->getEmail(). '-added' +1;

    $entity->setUsername($username);
    $entity->setEmail($email);
    $this->em->flush();
```

So the results on every add could be:

```
my-email@live.com-added-1
my-email@live.com-added-2
my-email@live.com-added-3
```

and so on..

I thought it can be done with count(). I could not find anything similar.

So how can I add numbers dynamically with php on this example?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I add numbers dynamically with php in this example? :)  @u_mulder

Comment: _“I t[h]ought it can be done with count().”_ - count() of what, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use **for loop** :

```
$rows = 10; //count of your rows
    for($i=1;$i<=$rows;$i++){
      $username = $entity->getUsername() . '-added-' .$i;
      $email = $entity->getEmail(). '-added-' .$i;
      $entity->setUsername($username);
      $entity->setEmail($email);
      $this->em->flush();
    }
```

Comment: Thnak you so much for replay, but this won't do it. The result is: my-email@live.com-added-1-added-1-added-1-added-1-added-1-added-1-added-1-added-1-added-1-added-1 in my db. @Ramki

Comment: Now, it's my-email@live.com-added1-added2-added3-added4-added5-added6-added7-added8-added9-added10. What I am trying to accomplish is when action is triggered, result will be my-email@live.com-added1, second time it will be added my-email@live.com-added2, third my-email@live.com-added3 and so on.. @Ramki

Comment: when you trigger this function ?

Comment: When I have more then one same username in db, I added this logic so response won't throw an error. @Ramki

Comment: are you fetched all user details from DB ?

Comment: No, it's in EasyAdmin controller within prePersistEntity() func. @Ramki

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the [Symfony UniqueEntity Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)
That way, defining you entity with :

```
@Assert\UniqueEntity(fields={"mail"})
@Assert\UniqueEntity(fields={"username"})
```

Will invalidate the form when the `$form->isValid()` method called in your controller will invalidate the form if another entity with this mail or username already exists.